# <script> Tag is not rendering within the php echo statement

Tags: javascript, php

I made simple **tryItYourself** type codeEditor. Into the text area i write my code. 
When a click the button `renderCode`, code will be render in the div next to it.
but whenever i used `<script>` tag in text editor it doesn't render anything that is inside the  tag.

Here is the code.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style>
#area {
    width: 48%;
    height: 500px;
}
#showCode {
    float: right;
    width: 48%;
    height: 500px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    border: 2px solid black;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) ; ?>" method="post">
<input type="submit" value="rederCode" style="display: block"><br>
<textarea id="area" name="code" placeholder="Enter your code here" >
<?php 
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {
echo $_POST["code"]; 
}
?>
</textarea>
<div id="showCode">
<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {
echo "'". $_POST['code'] .  " ' "; 
}
?>
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

It show me an error inside the console whenever i used `<script>` tag:

> The XSS Auditor refused to execute a script in
>   'http://localhost/textEditor.php' because its source code was found
>   within the request. The auditor was enabled as the server sent neither
>   an 'X-XSS-Protection' nor 'Content-Security-Policy' header.

Comment: Are you using some type of framework?

Comment: No, i'm not using any framework. I am using php on apache web server.

Comment: Your browser has prevented the script from showing because it believes it is a cross site scripting based attack (XSS).

Comment: But when i simply used in another file  like <?php echo "<script> document.write('hello'); </script> ?> it show hello into the browser.

Comment: if it is seems like cross site scripting attack then how can i use javascript in my tryItYourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The browser detected cross-site scripting vulnerabilities in your code.

> its source code was found within the request

indicates that the browser didn't run the script because the content of the script was sent in $_POST.  If you are sure your page is safe from XSS vulnerabilities, add the following PHP at the beginning of the file:

```
<?php
    header("X-XSS-Protection: 0");
?>
```

Comment: "If you are sure your page is safe from XSS vulnerabilities" — Which means you need to implement CSRF protection.